# Create pdf not showing Chart

Tags: jquery, angularjs, pdf, charts, jspdf

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.zingchart.com/angular/zingchart-angularjs.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<style>
#chart-1-top > div {
    display: none;
}


</style>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController" id="content">
  <input type="hidden" id="value" value="3"> 
    <div zingchart id="chart-11" zc-json="myJson" zc-width="100%" zc-height="568px"></div>
  </div>
  <button id="submit">Export to  PDF</button>
</body>


<script>


var app = angular.module('myApp',['zingchart-angularjs']);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope){
 var a=5;
 var b=4;
 var c=angular.element($('#value')).val();
 var d=16;
 var e=2;
  $scope.myJson = {
      type : 'line',
      series : [
        { values : [a,b,c,d,e] },

      ]
  };
});


</script>
<script>

var doc = new jsPDF(); 
var specialElementHandlers = { 
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) { 
        return true; 
    } 
};
$('#submit').click(function () { 
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, { 
        'width': 190, 
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers 
    }); 
    doc.save('sample-page.pdf'); 
});



</script>
```

Hi this is the code in which we tried to generate the chart using angular js.
but when we click on generate pdf button the chart is not showing on the pdf. the pdf shown blank without chart. i want to show the chart on the pdf

Answer (score 0):

I believe fromHTML is asynchronous so try this instead:

```
doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, { 
    'width': 190, 
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers 
}, function() {
    doc.save('sample-page.pdf');
});
```